# Where to get Android libraries of Drive API v2 and dependencies (maven is preferred)?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Has anyone figured out where to take libraries for compiling https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_4_set_up_the_sample ?

They explain on the same page how to get Drive API v2 libs through Eclipse. I'm not using Eclipse and using IDE for getting libs doesn't look right for programmer (automation, build server, etc). Although I wasn't able to find any maven repo with libs. Actually I'm not sure what artifacts names (or full set of jars) it should be.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their api maven repo:

```
<repository>
  <id>googleapis</id>
  <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
</repository>
```

and example dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
  <version>v2-rev33-1.12.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

Their maven repo does not allow listing, but you can build url like this to get jars:

http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev33-1.12.0-beta/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev33-1.12.0-beta.jar

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm sure this repo wasn't available when I asked the question. Then you don't have to put latest drive jar to your repository. Although all dependencies tweaking is still required for making this drive dependency compatible with Dalvik. I'll update maven  script in my answer with your advise as soon as I get everything working (on both desktop and Android).

Answer (score 2):

All Google API are there:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Unfortunately, as per my own search, the Drive SDK v2 is still in Beta right now (dec 2012) and is only available through Eclipse.

Regards

EDIT: look at [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=mavenrepo#hg/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev13-1.8.0-beta) !!!

Comment: Yeah it's beta. Although I don't see how and why this fact limits me to Eclipse for downloading libraries.

Comment: I have edited my answer, think that s what you where searching

Comment: This is what I tried actually. However it's v2 rev13 1.8.0, while through Eclipse you can get v2 rev33 1.12.0. I'm giving you the answer . Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I figured out how to use Google Drive libs from Maven.

Base Google client api libraries which are needed for Google Drive are in the Maven Central.
Actually there's 1.8.0 version of Google API Services v2 libs in google code maven [repo](http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/). This repository should be included in pom.xml:

```
    <repository>
        <id>google-api-services</id>
        <url>http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg</url>
    </repository>
```

Besides Google Drive library itself also some base API libraries are needed. Here is mvn for desktop:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev13-1.8.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

On Android more dependencies are need and also xpp3 transitive dependency should be excluded. Some handshake with google-play-services dependency is required as well.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-android</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0-beta</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.google.android.google-play-services</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.syncloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
        <version>4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev13-1.8.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

The google-play-services is referenced from google-api-client-android library in Maven Central. Although there's neither real nor stub jar in Maven Central. So you have to exclude this dependency. However you still have to provide this jar. You can download it through Android SDK Manager and install into your Maven repository. That what was done in my case and I referenced google-play-services version 4 (Gingerbread) in org.syncloud of Sonatype Maven repository.

For using latest Google Drive v2 libraries the one will have to download them through Eclipse and install to your Maven repository. This is what I have done in Syncloud project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.syncloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev33-1.12.0-beta-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Conclusion:
Using Google Drive v2 libraries from Maven on Android is possible. Although you should first fully understand all dependencies between Google Drive library and Google API Client libraries. Also you will have to install some libraries to your Maven, since latest Google Drive library and Google Play Services library aren't installed by Google to any Maven.

If anyone from Google Drive development team was reading this post, please relief pain of missing libraries in Maven.

Answer (score 1):

there is a Google plugin for Eclipse. With that you can import all google APIs. Just check it out in the Eclipse marketplace.

EDIT

[Here is a link to the plugin](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have done. Although Maven or at least pure download from http (which Maven repo provides as well) are preferable. Why I'm forced to use some specific Java IDE?

Comment: could you upvote the answer so that other people searching for this find this solution? Thanks :)