# What libraries I have to use for uploading the files to GOOGLE DRIVE

Tags: java, upload, google-api, google-drive-api

I found the example of upload the files to Google Drive:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/report.csv");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
.setFields("id")
.execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

The problem is I can not use it. Where can I found the libraries, which allow compile that code? 
My eclipse does not know the classes File() and driveService.

Comment: The fastest way to get up and running might be to create a Maven project.  Then update your POM file and let Maven do the work to pull in the required dependencies.  See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000539/where-to-get-android-libraries-of-drive-api-v2-and-dependencies-maven-is-prefer) for more information.

Comment: I installed the Maven plugin (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/setup). How can I use it in my project? I know the Maven group Id for the libraries, but I don't know what should I do with it..

Comment: Update your question with the relevant POM section.  Also let us know which IDE you are using.

Comment: I use  Eclipse for compiling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload the file to Google drive using API and error 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201839/upload-the-file-to-google-drive-using-api-and-error-403)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Here I ask a question about libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the `Java Quickstart` for Google Drive REST APIs here -
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java

Summary of the steps from the above link -

**Development environment** - Java 1.7+, Gradle 2.3+, a Google account with Google Drive enabled

**Step 1:** Create a project in `Google Developers Console` and `Turn on the Drive API`

**Step 2:** Prepare the project - download required dependencies, setup your gradle build

The following libraries are specifically needed

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev48-1.22.0'
```

**Step 3:** Set up the sample; write the code to authenticate your app to upload files to user's Google Drive

**Step 4:** Run the sample