# Upload the file to Google drive using API and error 403

Tags: java, upload, google-api, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I want to upload the zip-file to Google drive. I use Java Quickstart (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) as base. The code works. I modified it by the following code

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/report.csv");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
.setFields("id")
.execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Now my compiler shows the error 403.

```
c:\wd2>gradle -q run
юъЄ 23, 2016 8:02:06 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory se
tPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\Home\.credentials\
drive-java-quickstart
юъЄ 23, 2016 8:02:06 PM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory se
tPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\Home\.credentials\driv
e-java-quickstart
Credentials saved to C:\Users\Home\.credentials\drive-java-quickstart
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonRespo
nseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.fro
m(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClie
ntRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClie
ntRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest
.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest
.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest
.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:126)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished w
ith non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

How can I fix it?

The source code:

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DriveQuickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Drive API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Drive.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        Drive service = getDriveService();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
             .setPageSize(10)
             .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
             .execute();

        //*
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
        fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/zip");

        java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("c:\\profiles.zip");
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/zip", filePath);
        File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
        .setFields("id")
        .execute();
        System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId()); //*/
    }

}
```

Comment: I found the solution. I just changed the SCOPE:            from Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);    to       Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend changing the **SCOPE** from Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.**DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY**); to Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.**DRIVE**);

Here is more documentation on [**Google Drive API SCOPES**](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/DriveScopes.html).

1. When changing the SCOPE remember to delete your "**StoredCredential**" file that is stored within the **tokens** folder of your project.
2. **Run your program again** so that you will be **prompted** to **provide Google login credentials** to **allow** your program to **organize, add and edit** files on Google Drive.
3. Ensure that you **allow your program** to **organize, add and edit files** on Google Drive when granting permission in the authentication process.
4. The **authentication process** will **generate** a new  "**StoredCredential**" file that **will include** your **new SCOPE** which you have specified.

This worked for me hope it will work for you as well.